# Join Tables when master table has multiple fields matching one field on second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to display a two digit abbreviation instead of a number to represent our production machines as they route through the floor.

The problem is that the order table has 6 fields OP1, OP2,...,OP6 that are denoted with the OP#, but a second table holds the OP# with the 2 digit abbreviation I want to use use i.e. RD

I am just staring now because I have looked at this too long and could use another set of eyes for help.

[image: Example of Tables]

I was thinking just a plain join where order.op1 = workcenter.op, but what if I do not have an OP number in the OP1 field and it only appears in OP3?  Is this where a right join works(I must admit I am not sure I have ever used one)?

Comment: Sorry, this is MSSQL.  Obviously my first post here.  I just started a new job 4 weeks ago and it has been almost 4 years since I have done any query writing and I am pretty rusty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i only did the first three columns, I will leave it to you to do the other four.

```
SELECT ord.id
     , ord.job
     , o1.op_abbv AS op1
     , o2.op_abbv AS op2
     , o3.op_abbv AS op3
  FROM orders ord
       LEFT OUTER JOIN opmaster o1 ON ord.op1 = o1.op_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN opmaster o2 ON ord.op2 = O2.op_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN opmaster o3 ON ord.op3 = O3.op_id
       ORDER BY ORD.ID
```